# AngularJS Modal Close Calling JS Function Does Not Execute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Still trying to understand the intricacies of AngularJS, so excuse for my lack of better understanding.

I have a function:

```
function getTeams(){
  var onSuccess = function(results){
     $scope.myTeams = results.data;
     console.log($scope.myTeams);
  };

  var onFail = function(error){
    console.log(error);
  };

  dataService.getTeams().then(onSuccess, onFail);
};
```

dataService is just a JS file which has the service calls (i.e.):

```
var serviceFactory = [];

var _getTeams = function(){
  return $http.get(serviceUrl).then(function (results){
    return results;
  });
};

serviceFactory.getTeams = _getTeams;

return serviceFactory;
```

Initially, when I call that function, I am able to get a list of the teams I need.

But when I open a modal window, and upon closing of the modal window I call that same function, like:

```
$scope.openTeamModal = function(){
  $scope.modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'modal.html',
    controller: 'modalCtrl',
    backdrop: 'static'
  });

  this.modalInstance.result.then(
    function(results){
      getTeams();
    }
  )
}
```

When I set a breakpoint (in Chrome Debug console) on the line getTeams() right below the **modalInstance.result** line, the teams are actually being retrieved. But when I remove the breakpoint and simply let the application complete its process, the value for $scope.myTeams is not being updated properly.

Without Debug, console.log($scope.myTeams) will yield the original number of teams I am retrieving.

With Debug, console.log($scope.myTeams) yields the correct number of teams I am retrieving.

Any insight on how to resolve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `this.modalInstance` valid? From the looks of your code your assigning modal instance to the `$scope` not `this`

Comment: Yes, modalInstance is valid. The issue I have is not with the modal but with the function call which for some reason is not being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this
       return $http.get(serviceUrl).then(function (results){
           return results;
       });
will return an object immediately.  The .then(function... portion will then execute whenever the promise is fulfilled. So the results won't be available upon immediate return of your call to getTeams. Try this instead:

```
   return $http.get(serviceUrl);
```

and then

```
   var promise = getTeams();
   promise.then(function(results) {
      ......
   }
```